# How do I use Conditional Formatting based on due dates in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format cells in Excel 2013. I want the cells to get colored as green, yellow, and red based on how close they are with the target date (January 13, 2015 in this case).

I am unable to use conditional formatting as Excel says that relative formatting is not permitted within conditional formatting.

**Target:   06-01-2015**

```
01-01-2015
02-01-2015
03-01-2015
04-01-2015
05-01-2015
06-01-2015
07-01-2015
08-01-2015
09-01-2015
10-01-2015
```

If the date in the cell is more than 2 days of the target date, I want the cell to change color to Green. I used `=DATEDIF($N12,$N$9,"d")>=3` and the format changed to green.

If the date in the cell is exactly 2 days near the target date, I want the cell to change color to yellow. I used `=DATEDIF($N12,$N$9,"d")=2` and the format changed to yellow.

If the date in the cell is within 2 days of the target date, I want the cell to change color to red. I used `=DATEDIF($N12,$N$9,"d")<2` and the format changed to red only for 5th and 6th January. Apparently, it does not recognize negative values.

How can I get this to match the required colors?

Comment: Other than the minor edits I made to improve your question, you did a great job explaining what you are trying to do. Only this that needs clarification is the date format. Are those dates `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem using `DATEDIF` is it doesn't calculate negatives. Microsoft states:

> Displays a #NUM! error because start_date occurs before end_date
>   (#NUM!)

Therefore, the rule doesn't run as you entered it. Since Excel recognizes dates, use the simple function of `SUM` on this and it works as you described.

`=SUM($N$9-N12)>=3` for green
`=SUM($N$9-N12)=2` for yellow
`=SUM($N$9-N12)<2` for red

Here are the rules.

[image]

And the results.

[image]

*NOTE: My date format is `m/d/yyy`. This was done in 2010, but should be the same to 2013.*